# My Codeigniter method for safely deleting database entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I've been searching about deleting db entries in Codeigniter and I finally created a solution that I think is secure. I would really appreciate any feedback! I'm not sure if I'm doing this right..

**Advantages:**

- Uses POST request
- ID of entry to be deleted is
  validated
- Uses CSRF protection (automatically
  generated by Codeigniter)

In my example I'm deleting user submitted links (a DB table row contains a link title, link URL, an link description).

HTML: Database entires are contained within a form. Each entry has a form button with the respective link id in the `id` attribute.

```
<?php echo form_open('profile/remove_link'); ?>

<?php echo form_hidden('link_id', ''); //value will be populated via jquery ?>

<ul id="user_links">
    <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>

    <li><?php echo $row->link_title; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo auto_link($row->link_url, 'url', TRUE); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $row->link_description; ?></li>

    <button type="submit" class="remove" id="<?php echo $row->link_id ?>"  value="remove">Remove Link</button>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

</form>
```

JQUERY: When user clicks on the `remove` button, the respective link id is added to the the hidden text input named `link_id`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove').click(function() {
        var link_to_remove = $(this).attr("id");
        $("input[name=link_id]").val(link_to_remove);
    }); 
});
```

Upon clicking a remove button, it sends the id of link to be removed to controller `profile` and function `remove_link`

```
    function remove_link()
    {
        $this->load->model('Profile_model');
        $links_data['query'] = $this->Profile_model->links_read(); //get links from db to add in view

        //Validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('link_id', 'Link ID', 'trim|required|xss_clean|max_length[11]|numeric'); //validate link id

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) //if validation rules fail
        {           
            $this->load->view('profile/edit_links_view', $links_data);
        }
        else //success
        {
            $link_id =  $this->input->post('link_id'); //get id of link to be deleted
            $seg = 'user_links'; //used to redirect back to user links page
            $this->Profile_model->links_delete($link_id, $seg); //send link id to model function            
        }       
    }
```

MODEL

```
    function links_delete($link_id, $seg)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->tank_auth->get_user_id());
        $this->db->where('link_id', $link_id);
        $this->db->delete('user_links'); 
        redirect("/profile/$seg/");         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ids are unique integers in your database, you could remove these rules:

> trim|xss_clean|numeric

And add this one:

> #### is_natural_no_zero
>
> Returns FALSE if the form element contains anything other than a natural number, but not zero: 1, 2, 3, etc.

The [numeric rule](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) allows some characters you probably don't want, like decimals and negative. Here's the source (one line):

```
return (bool)preg_match( '/^[\-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/', $str);
```

If for some reason you are echo'ing the input back in your HTML output before validating, or are just paranoid, then by all means: xss_clean it up. Otherwise it's not really needed, as I don't think there's any possible method of XSS attacks that only use a number.

Reference:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29
- http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Also, you might want to add a `LIMIT 1` clause to your query, and definitely make sure to return a value (probably TRUE/FALSE) from your model so you know whether or not the query was successful, so you can give feedback to the user instead of *assuming* everything went well.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant feedback :) `is_natural_no_zero` is defintley a better validation rule. The links are great, I have been searching for good hacking examples and couldn't find any. In regards to `LIMIT 1` is this the correct way to do it in CI? `$this->db->where('link_id', $link_id)->limit(1);`

Comment: @CyberJunkie: If we can correctly assume that the id will always be unique, it's more of an optimization - you don't have to continue searching for the id after the first (and only) one is found. For columns that may not be unique, it simply makes sure only one row is affected (which may not be desired). But yes, your syntax is correct :)

Comment: yes the ids are unique but being paranoid, I will keep `LIMIT 1` lol

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I see wrong is that you don't validate who can and can't delete records. That's the only issue you should focus on. Permissions to check if the person sending the request of deletion is allowed to perform such operations. Other than that it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: The user validation is probably separate, run on every request.

Comment: I have `$this->db->where('user_id', $this->tank_auth->get_user_id());`. I'm deleting records from the logged in user only. Maybe I should also have `if( $this->tank_auth->get_user_id()) )` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rewriting controller and model a bit to make the flow more logical and provide better performance:

controller:

```
function remove_link()
{
    if ($this->input->post('link_id'))
    {
         //Validation
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('link_id', 'Link ID', 'is_natural_no_zero');
         if ($this->form_validation->run())
         {
             $seg = 'user_links'; //do you really need to assign it to variable ??
             $this->load->model('Profile_model');
             if ($this->Profile_model->links_delete($this->input->post('link_id')) //send link id to model function
             {
                 redirect('/profile/user_links'); // redirect user in controller and only when model returns true
             }else{
                 // inform user about error somehow, eg. by setting session flashdata and redirecting back to /profile/user_links
             }
        } 
    } // else statement here was a mistake as in case of form_validation failure nothing happened
    $this->load->model('Profile_model');
    $links_data['query'] = $this->Profile_model->links_read(); //get links from db to add in view
    $this->load->view('profile/edit_links_view', $links_data);
}
```

model:

```
function links_delete($link_id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->tank_auth->get_user_id())
             ->where('link_id', $link_id)
             ->delete('user_links'); // you can chain methods without writing always $this->db->
    return $this->db->affected_rows(); // returns 1 ( == true) if successfuly deleted
}
```

And as a side note in your jQuery code I suggest using $('#some_id') instead of $('input[name=XXXX]') - it saves some javascript code execution thus is faster

Comment: Thank you for the excellent suggestions! Returning affected rows is a good idea as well as using just the id attribute in jquery. Is it necessary however to check in the controller if an input was submitted? CI's built in function already checks to see if the item is set and returns false otherwise.

Comment: It is not necessary but your method has 2 different purposes depending on whether form was submitted (then lets process the data) or we should output the form. By the way please check the code once again as I made a little mistake previously